# Magento 2 - How to make responsive layout in Luma child theme?

Tags: mobile, layout, responsive-design, magento2

How to override styles-m css to set responsive layout? I just add custom blocks in footer area which are not responsive in mobile view. How to override styles-m in Luma child theme?

Thanks

[How to set mobile view?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNQKD.png)

Comment: Have you tried anything yet for this? Can you please show your code? As SO is not a free coding platform. It is for enthusiasts with having problems in their development.

Comment: I have done this.I added media queries in _extend.less file to set mobile layout.Thanks